# Suppress xparse message "Redefining document command"

Tags: warnings, xparse

I am trying to suppress messages of the form:

> ```
> *************************************************
> * LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
> * 
> * Redefining document command \MyMacro with arg. spec. 'm' on line 29.
> *************************************************
> ```

I tried to use [the `silence` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/silence), but can't determine how to correctly use that package for such errors.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{silence}

%% All these attempts do not solve this problem.
\WarningsOff[latex]
\WarningsOff[xparse]

\WarningFilter{latex}{LaTeX warning}
\WarningFilter{xparse}{LaTeX warning}

\WarningFilter{latex}{Redefining document command}
\WarningFilter{xparse}{Redefining document command}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{m}{\textbf{#1}}


\begin{document}
\MyMacro{some text}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{m}{\emph{#1}}%

\MyMacro{some more text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [`silence`](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) will only silence output if it matches exactly and if it's produced by a specific command.

Comment: Related Question: [Can I temporarily supress xparse's log messages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118677/can-i-temporarily-supress-xparses-log-messages).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `silence` for this, because `xparse` and all packages in the `l3kernel` suite (LaTeX3) use a very different method for issuing warnings, and definitely not the `\PackageWarning` macros on which `silence` relies.

The correct way for suppressing warnings is

```
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
```

The code connected with this option is

```
\DeclareOption { log-declarations = false }
  {
    \msg_redirect_module:nnn { LaTeX / xparse } { info }    { none }
    \msg_redirect_module:nnn { LaTeX / xparse } { warning } { none }
  }
```

that redirects *only* messages from the `xparse` module to "none".

Comment: Do you know which introduced this? It hasn't been there since forever AFAIK.

Comment: @Werner What I know is that the option didn't really work until some reworking on the kernel (last summer, I believe).

Comment: @Werner As egreg says, the option has been there for some time (since I rewrote `xparse`), but it was broken for some time!