# Can I temporarily supress xparse's log messages?

Tags: xparse, logging

I know that I can suppress all those annoying [`xparse`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) logging messages about redefining commands using the `log-declarations=false` package option.

I find that I can do this after `xparse` has been loaded by issuing the relevant commands:

```
\msg_redirect_module:nnn { LaTeX / xparse } { info }    { none }
\msg_redirect_module:nnn { LaTeX / xparse } { warning } { none }
```

at an appropriate juncture.  Then I can restore them with:

```
\msg_redirect_module:nnn { LaTeX / xparse } { info }    { info }
\msg_redirect_module:nnn { LaTeX / xparse } { warning } { warning }
```

My question is this: can I find out what the previous redirections were so that in the restoration code I can restore them to their previous value, not to some fixed choice?

Comment: As far as I can tell, redirection respects grouping.

Comment: @egreg but then I need to put the entire bit in between in a group and make all my definitions global.

Comment: A `\msg_redirect_module:nnn` command adds or updates an item in a property list variable or updates it; but this variable is private (`\l__msg_redirect_info_prop` or similar), so using it is discouraged.

Comment: I want to stress that egreg's solution is bad practice, especially if you plan to use it in a package.  Andrew, can you explicit your use case?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Oh dear!  My use-case is that in a particular package then I redefine a *lot* of things and all of them flash up the warning, so I want to suppress the warnings as they would only confuse a user.  But I want to do so "nicely" in that if they user does their own `xparse` stuff then they get the behaviour they expect, whether they chose to see the warnings or not.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Sorry to ask.  I could have guessed.  I think that this use case is very reasonable and probably quite common, and I'll try to think of a good interface for such cases.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch That'd be the best solution.  I'm a long way from "production ready" so there's no rush.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch This discussion was almost 4 years ago. Is there any advance since then for having a selective deactivation of xparse log (typically inside a package) ?

Answer (score 3):

A `\msg_redirect_module:nnn` command adds or updates an item in a property list variable or updates it; but this variable is private (`\l__msg_redirect_info_prop` or similar), so using it is discouraged.

However, this seem to work, but since it accesses private variables it's surely *not* recommended. Probably a feature request on the LaTeX3 mailing list is in order.

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_stacey_redirect_store_info_prop
\prop_new:N \l_stacey_redirect_store_warning_prop
\prop_new:N \l_stacey_redirect_store_error_prop
\tl_new:N \l__stacey_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \stacey_msg_redirect_module:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \prop_if_in:cnTF { l__msg_redirect_#2_prop } { /#1 }
   {
    \prop_get:cnN { l__msg_redirect_#2_prop } { /#1 } \l__stacey_temp_tl
    \prop_put:cnV { l_stacey_redirect_store_#2_prop } { /#1 } \l__stacey_temp_tl
   }
   {
    \prop_put:cnn { l_stacey_redirect_store_#2_prop } { /#1 } { #2 }
   }
  \msg_redirect_module:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \stacey_msg_restore_redirect_module:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_if_in:cnT { l_stacey_redirect_store_#2_prop } { /#1 }
   {
    \prop_get:cnN { l_stacey_redirect_store_#2_prop } { /#1 } \l__stacey_temp_tl
    \msg_redirect_module:nnV { #1 } { #2 } \l__stacey_temp_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \msg_redirect_module:nnn { nnV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{}
\stacey_msg_redirect_module:nnn { LaTeX / xparse } { warning } { none }
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{}
\stacey_msg_restore_redirect_module:nn { LaTeX / xparse } { warning }
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{}
```

The output on the terminal is

```
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
*
* Redefining document command \foo with arg. spec. '' on line 31.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
*
* Redefining document command \foo with arg. spec. '' on line 35.
*************************************************
```

You see that the second `\DeclareDocumentCommand` doesn't issue a warning.